# In DynamoDB using On-demand capacity, when does the available capacity ramp down?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am troubleshooting throttling issues with a DynamoDB table configured in on-demand mode. We have a table that sees pretty low average load with much larger peaks. During some of these peaks, we see throttling errors. I see from the [DynamoDB Developer's Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.PeakTraffic) that the peak capacity is increased to double the previous peak after a window of 30 minutes. When can we expect this capacity to ramp down? In the graph below, I see a period of a little over 24 hrs where the capacity was not throttled with ~3.4K Write Capacity Units (WCU) and then the following day where it was throttled with less than that amount.

So what I am trying to understand is, are there any rules or guidelines that govern the behavior for capacity ramping down from the previous high-water-mark? It looks like this happens in less than 24 hours but I would like to be a little more precise.

[image: load over 1 day with throttling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it on-demand capacity mode, there is no capacity to ramp up or ramp down per se. What there are, under the hood, are partitions and each partition can handle 3000 IOPS (a read is one IOPS and a write is three IOPS). So what the part of the docs you mention is referring to is DynamoDB tries to keep ahead of you in the number of partitions available that can support the number of IOPS you are trying to do. You can "scale up" that table to twice what table's previous high watermark for IOPS supported. Let's look at a concrete example. Any table that's been in on-demand capacity mode can support 12,000 IOPS, meaning it has at least 4 partitions. That 12,000 IOPS is what you can "by default" support. Next you start doing some traffic and get to 10,000 IOPS. DynamoDB will see this, react, and start adding partitions on your behalf. "Hey, this table is getting close to its max, I better add more partitions." This is not instantaneous though. DynamoDB tries to keep enough of partitions around to support you peaking to double your previous high water mark. I am oversimplifying what it is doing on your behalf, but hopefully you get the idea.

All of that said, if the numbers you have in the screen shot in the most capacity you have ever used (we are only looking at a slice of about a day), then the throttling you are seeing could be due to something besides capacity. It could be a hot key. Have you tried turning on [CloudWatch Contributor Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/contributorinsights.html) for a bit to let it gather data to see if it can nail down if there is a hot key? That would be my next step. You do not have to turn it on for a really long time, it does cost money, but long enough to get some real data about what is going on.

If you are not familiar with hot keys, Hot keys is a term used for items in a DynamoDB table that are read or written so many times that either: 1/ that item alone hits the per partition IOPS limit (3000) or 2/ requests for that item primarily, combined with other items in the partition are enough to reach the per partition IOPS limit. In the case of #2, DynamoDB will automatically move hot items on your behalf to an existing less used partition or a new partition. Depending on the configuration of the table, DynamoDB will be more or less aggressive in moving hot items to limit hot partitions. If the hot item alone is the troublemaker, DynamoDB may attempt to isolate it in its own partition, but at some point it could still hit the partition IOPS limitation and therefore cause throttling. DynamoDB taking this action is a reactive measure and it will do its best to alleviate the problem for you over time. Best practice is to not get into this situation in the first place by designing your key schema to avoid this.

Hot keys can occur due to a few issues:

- The most common reason is incorrect schema design when choosing a partition key
- An unanticipated increase in traffic on a select few keys.
- A new access patterns that was not been accounted for

Comment: Do the partitions you describe at the beginning line up with partition keys in the DB structure? I had come across the [per-partition limits](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/) but didn't realize until taking another look that our jobs would all be writing to the same partition key. I have also turned on Contributor Insights for this table, but need to wait until our weekly peak traffic before it will be useful.